# fetch data from the internet

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to fetch data from the server by using HTTP request so I read the flutter document  to know how to do that I follow this [article](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) to do it

when I ran the app only the **CircularProgressIndicator** are working there are no data on the screen

anyone can tell me why

Comment: please show your code

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#complete-example

Comment: the complete example is the code that i used @SamiKanafani

Comment: what is the output in the logs? maybe you are not able to connect to the internet

Comment: the internet works in my emulator.. there's no output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it by changing

> future : post

to

> future: FuturePost()